# VSCode vim highlight current word

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

vscode version 1.22.1

Now [vscodevim (0.11.3)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension work like this:

[image]

But I want to see matched words:

[image]

With just keys remap I can't select lines in visual mode.

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug. We are already [tracking the same problem here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46978)